# How to compute an orthogonal projection of a vector that is not in the vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, projective-geometry

I am working on a problem where I found an orthonormal basis of polynomials that span the vector space V of polynomials $\vec p$ of degree at most 2.

But part(b) of the problem asks to use part(a) to solve the minimization problem

$$\min_{p\in V} \int_{-1}^1 (p(x)-x^3)^2dx$$

So, I know that I want to minimize $(p(x) - x^3)$.  So perhaps, I can compute the orthogonal projection of $x^3$ onto the space $V$.  This orthogonal projection of $x^3$ onto $V$ will be of minimum norm, which gives us what we want.

However, how can I actually compute this when $x^3$ is not even a vector in $V$?

I had thought of using my orthonormal basis, computing a orthogonal projection matrix, and then applying the matrix to $x^3$ to get some result.  This wouldn't make sense, unfortunately ...

So how can I proceed?

Thanks,

Comment: What's your inner product?

Comment: Hi @Nameless, it is: $$<p,q> = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^1 p(x)q(x)dx$$

Comment: Oo, hi @Nameless, I think...I should just run Gram-Schmidt once more, on $x^3$, which should give a vector orthogonal to the first 3 vectors that spanned the polynomial space.  This would also form a basis for a the space of polynomials of degree at most 3.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: see Bernard's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  general answer, for a subspace $V$ with an orthonormal basis$(u_i)_{1\le i\le n}$, is
$$p(x)=x-\sum_{i=1}^n\langle x,u_i\rangle u_i.$$

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much @Bernard :-)